# Adding Javascript Function to Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets

Hi I was wondering how to format a javascript function as simple as:

```
function calculate()
{
alert('calculate Cost');
}
```

so that it can be placed into the assets/javascripts/application.js and be called from the view.

On my view I am calling the function by:

```
<input type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="calculate">
```

For some reason the function is not being called but it works if I put the alert message via inline: 
    onclick="alert('calculate Cost');"

Answer (score 0):

Application.js

```
function calculate() {
alert('calculate Cost');
}
```

HTML Page

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="external.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" onClick="calculate();" value="calculate">
</body>
</html>
```

That code will alert calculate cost when you click on the button.

Comment: Im trying to add this to the rails framework, so in my views/layout/application.html.erb I have <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> put in which should do the same as the script you suggested to add to the <head></head>